# Position fixed stop in particular section

Tags: html, css

Please see my fiddle. In this fiddle, the black box is fixed on page. If we scroll the page the black box is overlap the map also. I want to stop the fixed position before the map. If we scorll the page after the map, black box should stay before the map. How can I do?

CSS:

```
.item{ background:#eee; padding:10px; width:50%; margin-bottom:15px;}
.new_icon{ position:fixed; width:100px; height:100px; background:#000; right:10px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6f8HK/

Comment: can we use javascript (jQuery)?

Comment: There are a lot of libraries that do such things. Check out http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em

Comment: Is it possible to do? But css is better.

Comment: YOu can use z-index. position it at back of map.

Comment: No need for z-index, just set the iframes position to relative

Answer (score 3):

No need for javascript, add an id to your iframe, set the css to:

```
#map
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

And give your fixed element a lower z-index:

```
.new_icon {
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#000;
    right:10px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f8HK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index: -1;` to `.new_icon`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6f8HK/4/)**

Comment: But the icon not behind the map. It should stay before the map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7RSg/).

JQUERY:

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 450)
     {
        $('.new_icon').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.new_icon').fadeIn();
     }
 });
```

NOTE : use can use .show/.hide if you don't like the fadein/fadeout effect.

Comment: thank you. I will try this code and get back to you.

Comment: you can change the "450" value depends on how long from the top would you like for .new_icon to fade out.